# Linking to app store with a "space" in app name

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, app-store

I want to link from my app directly to the app store.

I am using this code:

```
   var url  = NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/companyname/appname")
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true  {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
            }
```

When the name of the app has no space in it, it works fine. But is there is a space in the app name, It does not link to the app itself, but it links to the page with all my apps. How come?

---

Example: if app name = bobbie , I use:

```
var url  = NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/mycompany/bobbie")
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true  {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
            }
```

(works prefectly)

But it app name  = bob bie , I use:

```
var url  = NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/mycompany/bob-bie")
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true  {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
            }
```

But this doesn't link to the app...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching App Store from App in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940109/launching-app-store-from-app-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace the space by %20 using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:

```
let link = "itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/mycompany/bob bie"
if let linkWithPercentEscape = link.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    println(linkWithPercentEscape)
    if let url  = NSURL(string: linkWithPercentEscape) {
        println(url)
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)  {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the link provided in iTunes connect for your app.

1. Open [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)
2. Log in
3. Click "My apps"
4. Select your app
5. Click "More"
6. Copy link for "Show in App Store"