# How any link of HTML in Mail opens App or Browser respectively in iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, email

I seen few mails with links opens their respective Applications if installed otherwise opens link in browser.

Searched for same result and got [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406992/how-to-open-app-or-open-link-using-a-single-button-from-email).

Javascript function not working in html content, I have read that many mail client do not support javascript due to security reason.

HTML with href link of custom url Scheme working fine, if app installed on device. But app not installed on device then what to do ?

```
<a href="customurl://test">App name</a>
```

How to handle if app not installed on device how to open browser with respective link ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register a custom app opening URL scheme with Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4)

Comment: @NadirLaskar This is not duplicate of it, I know URL scheme and that is working, Question is if app not installed on device how to handle that ?