# Redirect to app-store on a press of a button

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I would like to redirect to the app-store to a specific app, using its ID upon receiving a button tap. I have tried all the answers here on stack overview however none worked for me, they are most likely outdated such as these:
[Open AppStore through button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882936/open-appstore-through-button), [Launching App Store from App in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940109/launching-app-store-from-app-in-swift), [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

I tried the following URLs, however I get false via `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(:_)`:

`"itms-apps://apple.com/app/{appId}"`

`"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/developer/{appId}"`

`"itms-apps://apps.apple.com/cz/app/{developer}/{appId}"`

How to currently go about redirecting to App-Store? Can this still be done via URL, or do we have to use the StoreKit exclusively?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Added thread links

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to open the App Store?  Normally using [`SKStoreProductViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller) Gives a better user experience as they don't need to leave your app.

Comment: They are all wrong.  An App Store link doesn't even starts with the itms-apps protocol.

Comment: Take a good look at one of the solutions posted at Open AppStore through button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open AppStore through button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882936/open-appstore-through-button)

Comment: I ended up using the `SKStoreProductViewController`, I was really interested if there is any way to open AppStore directly, just out of curiosity

Answer (score -1):

```
if let url  = URL(string: "itms-apps://apple.com/app/id\(appid)"),
   UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
   UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: That's wrong.  Or tell us what happens after you try it for yourself.

Comment: simple, it will redirect to app store.